How can I define a custom likelihood function using PYMC?
While performing MCMC using emcee package, I can simply define a custom likelihood and posterior functions and put them into the emcee.EnsembleSampler . The whole code:
def log_likelihood(theta):
    teff_k, logg_k, feh_k, CFE, NFE, OFE, MGFE, ALFE, SIFE, CAFE, SCFE, TIFE, VFE, CRFE, COFE, NIFE = theta
    VMIC, HE_ABUN, LIFE, NAFE, SFE, KFE, MNFE, CUFE, ZNFE, YFE, SRFE, BAFE, NDFE, LAFE, EUFE, ZRFE, PRFE, CEFE, SMFE, AUFE, THFE, UFE = otherparams
    input_para = [teff_k, logg_k, feh_k, VMIC, HE_ABUN, LIFE,
                  CFE, NFE, OFE, NAFE, MGFE, ALFE,
                  SIFE, SFE, KFE, CAFE, SCFE, TIFE,
                  VFE, CRFE, MNFE, COFE, NIFE, CUFE,
                  ZNFE, YFE, SRFE, BAFE, NDFE, LAFE,
                  EUFE, ZRFE, PRFE, CEFE, SMFE, AUFE,
                  THFE, UFE]
    input_para = np.array(input_para).T
    input_para = torch.tensor(input_para, dtype=torch.float64).view(1, -1)
    # use Transformer model to predict and calculate chi_square
    model1 = Transformer(num_layers, d_model, num_heads, d_ff, dropout, input_p_dim, output_s_dim)
    predict_flux_7718 = model1(input_para)
    chi_squared = np.sum(residn ** 2 / yerrn ** 2 + np.log(yerrn ** 2))
    return -0.5 * chi_squared

.....
def log_probability(theta):
    lp = log_prior(theta)
    if not np.isfinite(lp):
        return -np.inf
    return lp + log_likelihood(theta)

.....
 sampler = emcee.EnsembleSampler(nwalkers, ndim, log_probability,
                                    pool=pool,
                                    moves=[(emcee.moves.DEMove(), 0.01),(emcee.moves.DESnookerMove(), 0.01)])

But if I want to change emcee to pymc package, how can I define this likelihood function? For example  likelihood = pm.Potential('likelihood', log_likelihood(theta))?

did you read https://www.pymc.io/projects/examples/en/latest/howto/blackbox_external_likelihood_numpy.html ?
